# Add channel as follower according the two users

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

Im trying via Automated Action to auto add Channel according the 2 users where they are followers.

Code so far:

```
record.message_subscribe(partner_ids=[record.user_id.partner_id.id, record.x_studio_subcontractor.user_id.partner_id.id])
```

The above code make the 2 users followers, what code should apply so I can make their channel also follower to task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for chat channel between this two user both partner should be member of this channel, and the type
of the chat channel is `'chat'`, for private channel the type of channel is `'channel'` user can have multiple channels.

```py
partner_ids = [record.user_id.partner_id.id, 
              ecord.x_studio_subcontractor.user_id.partner_id.id]

channel_ids = self.env['mail.channel'].search([('channel_partner_ids', '=', partner_ids[0]),
                                         ('channel_partner_ids', '=', partner_ids[1]),
                                         ('public', '=', 'private'),
                                         ('channel_type', '=', 'chat'),  # only chat channel it should be only one
                                         ]).ids or None

record.message_subscribe(partner_ids=partner_ids, channel_ids=channel_ids)
```

@Fotic

With the below attributes on search is not adding the channel (probably because there was 2 channels (Announcements and the Private))

```
('public', '=', 'private'),
('channel_type', '=', 'chat'),
```

My final  solution:

```
partner_ids = [record.user_id.partner_id.id,record.x_studio_subcontractor.user_id.partner_id.id]

channel_ids = record.env['mail.channel'].search([('channel_partner_ids', '=', partner_ids[0]),
                                         ('channel_partner_ids', '=', partner_ids[1]),
                                         ('group_ids', '=', False),
                                         ]).ids or None

record.message_subscribe(partner_ids=partner_ids, channel_ids=channel_ids)
```

Anyway thank you very much for the help @Charif DZ

Comment: @Fotic love the way you think, what it matter is the idea and you understood that you need to figure out the correct domain Thanks for accepting my answer